# Declaration merging of interfaces in inherited class namespace

Tags: typescript

This doesn't seem to be covered in the manual.

I'm curious about why interfaces with the same name, in separate but inherited class namespaces, are not merged. The example below shows that the second interface shadows the first instead of being merged with it. Since members of the inherited namespace are visible, my gut was thinking the interfaces would be merged. I realize that I can explicitly declare `Bar.IOptions` to extend `Foo.IOptions`, I'm just wondering if the current behavior is as intended?

```
class Foo {
    constructor(options: Foo.IOptions = {}) {
        this._a = options.a || 0;
    }
    private _a: number;
}


namespace Foo {
    export interface IOptions {
        a?: number;
    }

    export const c = 12;
}


class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor(options: Bar.IOptions) {
        super();
        this._b = options.b;  // okay
        this._c = Bar.c;      // okay, inherited from Foo
        this._a2 = options.a; // fail
    }

    private _b: string;
    private _c: number;
    private _a2: number;
}


namespace Bar {
    export interface IOptions {
        b?: string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the fully qualified names are different—one is `Foo.IOptions` and the other is `Bar.IOptions`.

Note that declaration merging only occurs when they have the same fully qualified name:

```
namespace Foo {
    export interface IOptions {
        a?: number;
    }
}

namespace Foo {
    export interface IOptions {
        b?: string;
    }
}

var options: Foo.IOptions = {};
options.a; // works
options.b; // works
```

---

Also, realize that the constructors of `Foo` and `Bar` take different types. `Foo` takes `Foo.IOptions` and `Bar` takes `Bar.IOptions`:

You can't pass `Foo` an object of type `Bar.IOptions`...

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor(options: Bar.IOptions) {
        super(options); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

...but you can pass it an object that is `Foo.IOptions`...

```
class Bar extends Foo {
    constructor(options: Bar.IOptions) {
        super({ a: 5 }); // works
    }
}
```